# How to use static image resources with uibinder?

Tags: image, gwt, uibinder

I have a java class with uibinder layout file where I want to make reference to an image and display it within a focusPanel.

What is the best way of using static images within uibinder? And why might my image not be found?

```
src/main/java/de/myProject:
> .ui.xml
> .java
> image.png
```

ui.xml:

```
<g:FocusPanel>
    <g:Image url="image.png"/>
</g:FocusPanel>
```

Result: 404 image not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put this image in a publicly accessible folder on your web server. It cannot be inside the /src folder.

Comment: can I put it somewhere to having eclipse auto-copy it on deployment?

Comment: Put it in your /war folder.